# How to inject a parameter from redux to a function in React

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a class like the one below, I added a new parameter in mapStateToProps, and I can see it when rendering. I don't know how to pass it to the onClick method. Any Idea? I prefer not to pass it directly when I call the function, there are other parameters already accessible that are not passed directly.

```
class A extends Component{
  static propTypes = {
    myValue: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  onClick = (param1, param2) => {
    >>>I want to access myValue here<<<
  }

  render() {
    const { myValue } = this.props
      return (
        <MyCompoment
          onClick={this.onClick}
        >
      )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  myValues: getMyValue(state),
})
```

Comment: isn't `myValues` accessible to you via `this.props.myValues`?

Comment: it is actually, I though there was another way because I already have some parameters that are available without accessing props...

Comment: onClick = (param1, param2) => {

Comment: an event handler is passed a synthetic Event object by react. So that will be one of the parameters. What is second paramter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it like:

```
onClick = (param1, param2) => {
    const test = this.props.myValues;
}
```

or like render method:

```
onClick = (param1, param2) => {
    const { myValue } = this.props;
}
```